# CloudFormation Hooks do not push logs to Cloudwatch Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am developing a Cloudformation Hook. I can successfully deploy it and my custom handlers are executed. However, I cannot see any CloudWatch log group, and thus cannot debug the Hook logic.

```bash
aws configure
cfn generate
cfn submit --set-default
HOOK_TYPE_ARN="arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:563262xxxxx:type/hook/My-Dummy-Hook"

aws cloudformation set-type-configuration \
  --configuration file://type_config.json \
  --type-arn $HOOK_TYPE_ARN \
  --region eu-central-1
```

When I select my Hook, go to Edit -> Edit logging config, I can see the following json:

```json
{
  "logGroupName": "my-dummy-hook-logs",
  "logRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::563262xxxxx:role/CloudFormationManagedUplo-LogAndMetricsDeliveryRol-KYUY5H9D4XQN"
}
```

This role does exist, it has all the necessary policies to create log groups, etc.:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I still cannot see any logs in Cloudwatch, nor the log group is created. An interesting observation is that I cannot change this json via AWS console, it always throws an error (although I specify a valid role or log group):

```
Please use arn or specify a type
JSON
```

Weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with me was that I forgot to specify log level in the handler code:

```py
import logging

# Use this logger to forward log messages to CloudWatch Logs.

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOG.setLevel(logging.INFO)            # <- this line was missing
```

In other words, if not set explicitly, the default logger level will be used, i.e. `WARNING`. That means that you won't see any log stream in Cloudwatch Logs if you call `LOG.debug("test")` or `LOG.info("test")` in your handler code.